# Flask and SQLAlchemy db.session.commit not working

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When I add a test user to the `User` table, it adds fine and it is fine even when I execute `db.session.add(u)`, but it throws error when I execute `db.session.commit()`.

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Integer(120), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.Integer(120), unique=True)
    configkey = db.Column(db.Integer(200), unique=True)
    dob = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    country = db.Column(db.Integer(120))
    friends = db.relationship('Friend', backref = 'friendof', lazy = 'dynamic')


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.name)

class Friend(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Integer(120), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.Integer(120), unique=True)
    dob = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    country = db.Column(db.Integer(120))
    lastmessage = db.Column(db.Integer(1500))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<FriendName %r>' % (self.name)
```

**--Edit**, including the error message in Python console:

```
>>> u = models.User(name="sd", email="e")                                                                                                                      
>>> db.session.add(u)
>>> db.session.commit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 149, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 721, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 354, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 334, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1818, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1936, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 58, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1900, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 372, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 525, in execute
    uow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 64, in save_obj
    table, insert)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 569, in _emit_insert_statements
    execute(statement, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 662, in execute
    params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 761, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 874, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1024, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 196, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 867, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 324, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: user u'INSERT INTO user (name, email, configkey, dob, country) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' ('sd'
, 'e', None, None, None)
```

Comment: you didn't do `db.create_all()` before running your app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm looking at your stack trace (specifically the last line) and it looks as though your table doesn't exist yet.

Before you can use your new models with your database the tables and columns must be present. The good news is that SQLAlchemy can do this for you.

Try calling the following from anywhere within your program:

```
# Creates the schema on the database
db.create_all()
```

Just be sure to remove this when you're done!

Ideally you'd have another file you call from the command line that imports your flask app and then runs this command. For example...

```
# Replace these with your main file and the name of your flask object
from myapp import app 
# And this one with the name of your database file and object
from database import db 

db.create_all()

print "Database ready!"
```

**Edit:**
The `db.create_all()` command won't modify existing tables, similarly tables won't automagically change themselves after you've run `db.create_all()`. You can however for example, create a new table and then re-run the function and have it appear.

To properly handle upgrades to your database though, I recommend looking into [Flask-Migrate](http://flask-migrate.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), especially if your app will eventually be used in a production environment.

The quick and dirty method I use during initial development is to just delete the database and create it again if the changes are too large.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked just flawlessly.. just a small doubt, DO I have to execute the command everytime I change the model, and migrate the database or once is enough??

Comment: Hi Vinoth, glad to hear it worked! I've updated my answer to give you some more information. Please mark it as accepted if you found it useful. Thanks!

Comment: You should look into [Alembic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/alembic) to handle your migrations. There is also a flask-alembic.

Comment: Damn it!  I missed `db.create_all()` statement.