# SQLAlchemy with Flask db.session.commit() not working

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, sql-update

I've got a similar problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401968/flask-and-sqlalchemy-db-session-commit-not-working) so inserting new records to db is working but updating not.

Difference is: I'm not getting any error message and I DO `db.create_all()` each time I start my app.

1. I initiate the app_context and db:

   ```
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://karolina@127.0.0.1/tests_results'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
    db.init_app(app)
    app_context = app.app_context()
    DataBaseController.init(app_context)
   ```
2. Then I run threads in the main app with an app_context as parameter, then I have a method that creates record and each thread that is a function that in the end - always updates one record in the database.

update_test_result method from DataBaseController:

```
@staticmethod
    def update_test_result(app_context):
        with app_context:
            db.session.commit()
```

**EDIT: The hint with multiple db instances/ current session could be it** - though I am really confused how this should be done. Seems to me that, maybe along with the appcontext, I should pass also the db from the app.py - in an act of extreme desperation I decided to pass the db and appcontext from the main app basically to every function - no result...As to the way I'm doing it now:

a)   I have a script database.py which declares an "empty" db (without a model):

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

b) Then I have models.py that imports the db from the above and declares the model like this:

```
from database_management.database import db

class Result(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(150), primary_key=True)
    result = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    status = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

c) Finally I connect the db with the model I created in the main app and I pass the app_context to each thread that updates records in db.

Main app.py:

```
db.init_app(app)
app_context = app.app_context()
DataBaseController.init(app_context, db)
```

This is how I initiate the db in the DataBaseController:

```
from database_management.database import db
@staticmethod
    def init(app_context, db):
        with app_context:
            db.create_all()
            DataBaseController.create_bots()
            db.session.commit()
```

Loop from the main app:

```
test_cases = TestCasesLoader.split_test_cases(dialog_cases, db, app_context)  # here I create records
    threads_list = list()
    for test_case in test_cases[:10]:
        threads_list.append(Thread(target=test_case.run_test_case, args=(db, app_context, bot_config)))  # and here I update them
```

Creating the records:

```
@staticmethod
    def split_test_cases(dialog_cases, db, appcontext):
        db_name = dialog_cases.get("bot_name")
        for test_case in dialog_cases.get("test_case_list"):
            test_result = DataBaseController.get_test_result(db, appcontext, test_id)
            if test_result:
                DataBaseController.clean_result_data_in_db(db, appcontext, test_result)
            else:
                test_result = {
                    'id': test_id,
                    'status': 'IN_PROGRESS'
                }
                test_result = Result(test_result)
                DataBaseController.add_result_to_db(db, appcontext, test_result)
```

Creating in the DataBaseController:

```
@staticmethod 
    def add_result_to_db(db, appcontext, result):
        with appcontext:
            db.session.add(result)
            db.session.commit()
```

Updating in the thread:

```
def update_passed_result_in_db(self, appcontext):
    print("passed")
    result = DataBaseController.get_test_result(appcontext, self.test_id)
    result.result = self.test_passed
    result.status = 'DONE'
    with appcontext:
        db.session.commit()
```

And that's the updating in the DataBaseController:

```
from database_management.database import db

def update_passed_result_in_db(self, db, appcontext, human_said):
        result = DataBaseController.get_test_result(db, appcontext, self.test_id)
        result.result = self.test_passed
        result.status = 'DONE'
        with appcontext:
            db.session.commit()
```

Please, let me know if you have any ideas of what I could be doing wrong.
What's super interesting, when I experimented like this:

```
def update_passed_result_in_db(self, db, appcontext):   
result = DataBaseController.get_test_result(db, appcontext, self.test_id)
        cprint.err(type(result))
        result.id = self.test_id
        result.result = self.test_passed
        result.status = 'working'
        with appcontext:
            db.session.add(result)
            db.session.commit()
```

The record is added properly...

Comment: To narrow down the possibilities, you don't happen to have multiple `db` instances of the `SQLAlchemy` class from Flask-SQLA? I.e. the `db` used in `db.session.commit()` is the same from which models inherit `db.Model`?

Comment: Are you sure the object from `get_rest_result` is part of the current session? Because I'm far from sure of that.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I think you are right - could you please have a look at the section in my question that I added which starts with "EDIT"?

Comment: @KenKinder I think you are right - could you please have a look at the section in my question that I added which starts with "EDIT"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be indeed connected with the app context.

This one did not work:

```
result = db.session.query(Result).filter_by(id=test_id).first()
result.id = self.test_id
result.result = self.test_passed
result.status = 'working'
with appcontext:
    db.session.commit()
```

This one did the job:

```
result_data = {
    'status': 'working'
}
with appcontext:
    result = Result.query.filter_by(id=self.test_id).update(result_data)
    db.session.commit()
```

That's because querying the data and updating it should be done within one app context, not separately.

Comment: Running `.update()` more or less skips the ORM. It's the equivalent of running raw SQL. There's still something wrong with your sessions, I believe. If I were you, I would try putting the entire update in one app context, though I'm not sure that's the issue. Alternatively, if you have a short example of an app one could test, that might work.

Comment: @KenKinder you're right. When I put query'ing the result, then changing it and comitting within ONE appcontext and not separately - it's working